# ifelse in a mutate function in r

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to add a column with a condition using the mutate function in r, but keep getting an error. The code is straight from the teacher's lecture, but yet an error occurs. The LineItem column is a factor class, I am not sure if that make a difference.
Please advice on what I am missing.

Thank you,
Avi

```
df <- read.csv('ities_short.csv')

colSums(is.na(df))

sl <- str_length(df$LineItem)
avg <- mean(str_length(df$LineItem))

df <- df %>% mutate(LineItem_LongName = ifelse(sl > avg), 1, 0)
```

Error in ifelse(sl > avg) : argument "yes" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 2):

You have placed ')' at wrong places. The general syntax for ifelse is: 
ifelse(cond,value if true, value if false)

```
df <- read.csv('ities_short.csv')

colSums(is.na(df))

sl <- str_length(df$LineItem)
avg <- mean(str_length(df$LineItem))

df <- df %>% mutate(LineItem_LongName = ifelse(sl > avg, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nirbhay Singh answer is correct. However, if you compare two vectors, it's generally better to use `dplyr::if_else` because it is stricter regarding `NA` values :

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(LineItem_LongName = if_else(sl > avg, 1, 0))
```

See [the doc](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't create separate objects and use it in dataframe, instead keep them in dataframe itself. You can remove the columns later which you don't need. Moreover, you can do this without `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
   mutate(temp = str_length(LineItem), 
          LineItem_LongName = as.integer(temp > mean(temp)))
```

---

Or in base R :

```
df$temp <- nchar(df$LineItem)
transform(df, LineItem_LongName = +(temp > mean(temp)))
```